# Using a bootstrap button with link to devise page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, devise

Full disclosure, I'm a no00b. That said... I'm trying to use a bootstrap button that when clicked links to a devise registration page. I either get an error that I have an undefined method or it completely messes up my bootstrap format. Can someone please explain what is going on?

This line of code messes up the bootstrap formatting

```
  <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, :class => "btn btn-success" %>
```

Edit: rake routes path shows I have new_user_registration_path

```
    new_user_session GET    /auth/login(.:format)                   devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /auth/login(.:format)                   devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /auth/logout(.:format)                  devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /auth/secret(.:format)                  devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /auth/secret/new(.:format)              devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /auth/secret/edit(.:format)             devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /auth/secret(.:format)                  devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /auth/secret(.:format)                  devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /auth/register/cancel(.:format)         devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /auth/register(.:format)                devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /auth/register/cmon_let_me_in(.:format) devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /auth/register/edit(.:format)           devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /auth/register(.:format)                devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /auth/register(.:format)                devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /auth/register(.:format)                devise/registrations#destroy
```

Comment: define 'messes up the bootstrap formatting'. Can you include screenshots or something that would allow us to see the issue?

Comment: paste your devise registration related routes

Comment: This is the error I get undefined local variable or method `new_user_regiratration' for #<#<Class:0x007fab9f7ae9f8>:0x007fab9bc1a428>

Comment: Yes, please show us what you mean by "messes up bootstrap formatting".